# Need to carry check-box data from one page to another using PHP

Tags: php

I am new to php and am not quite clear on what to do to carry my information from the first page to the next and then submit it to my email when they are done filling out contact information.

I need the script to work as follows:

Step1: User clicks the input check-boxes for the field they want that is stored in an array

ex:

```
        < input type="checkbox" name="Sound[]" value="item1" > item1
```

and clicks a button i have written as

```
       < input type="image" name="Submit"  class="" alt="" src="images/contact1.png" border="0" >
```

Step2: The information from the check-boxes they have clicked needs to be carried over to the next page where they will fill out their contact info. Name email phone etc.

ex:

```
     <tr>
     <td valign="top">
      <label for="telephone">Telephone Number *</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
      <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
     </td>
    </tr>
```

Step3. All of this information should be sent to my email upon button press for me to contact them  :D

```
   <tr>
     <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">
      <input type="image" name="Contact" class="contactbutton" alt="" src="images/contact.jpg"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
```

I can pull the information from my inputs but do not know how to carry to the next page!
Can I do it all in the same php script? or does each page need a different php script?

Please help!

Thanks Paul

Comment: Sorry it was so late, but i did post my answer down below with an example on how to set the post to a session array and handle the data in it. Hope it helps

Comment: thanks so much DMS - i got it working :D the session array was def the way to go! also thank you shrmn and LongJourney! all of your input has taught me a lot and I could not have done it without you

Comment: Thats awesome, glad to help -if you could accept my answer that would also be great. Either wya glad i could help and Welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

```
you can do it with a form and send it to the page2.php. value will be stored in 
$_POST['S'] for the checkbox


<form action="page2.php" method="post">

<input type="checkbox" name="S" value="item1" > item1
<input type="SUBMIT" >

</form>

------------------
page2.php

echo($_POST['S']); // will be item1
```

Comment: thanks for helping! Do I have to give each item a different name? or will they all be available in S? what does value do in this situation?


also will I be able to use one submit button for all the check-box?

Comment: OP I think wanted an array of selected answers instead of individual $_POST results. Maybe offer him a $_SESSION ARRAY alternative based on his question

Comment: yes I am looking more for a session array type setup that I could use like this to send to my email as a string- thanks DMS     

-------------------------------------------------------------


 $soundinfo = $_POST['Sound'];
  if(empty($soundinfo))
  {
    $email_message .= "No sound selection.";
  }
  else
  {
    $N = count($soundinfo);
    echo("$N");
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {
      $email_message .= "".clean_string($soundinfo[$i])."\n ";
    }
  }

Comment: @dark9911 I'm on mobile right now and can't respond in code so hopefully someone else will write a session array option for you. If not ill get to it later tonight. Good luck

Comment: haha okay thanks DMS - ill keep messing with what I can find on the web/books for now - Will post results if I can get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

```
     $_SESSION array is better. to use it you need to put session_start(); at start of   
     every page that will use your $_SESSION variable i.e 

    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['S'])){
    $_SESSION['h'] = $_POST['S'];

    echo($_SESSION['h']); } //output value in checkbox
    ?>
    <html><body>
    <form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="S" value="item1" > item1
    <input type="SUBMIT" value="item1" > 


   Once this script is run you can accesS value in $_SESSION['h'] in other pages.  
   the data will be deleted when you close browser. 

----------------------------------

page2.php
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['h'])){ //check if $_SESSION['h'] has been set a value

echo  $_SESSION['h']; //output value stored in var
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will ultimately still require the use of POST data to get the checkbox status from your page.

Page 1:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // If postdata is received then redirect to next page
    if(isset($_POST['Sound'])) {
        $_SESSION['Sound'] = $_POST['Sound'];
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/page2.php');
        exit;
    }
?>
<form method="post" action="page1.php">
    Sound? <input type="checkbox" name="Sound" value="item1"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Page 2:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // If postdata is received then redirect to next page
    if(isset($_POST['telephone']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $_SESSION['telephone'] = $_POST['telephone'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/page3.php');
        exit;
    }
?>

<form method="post" action="page2.php">
    <!-- If you want to output the previously saved data in a disabled item -->
    Sound? <input type="checkbox" name="Sound" value="item1" disabled="disabled" <?php if($_SESSION['Sound'] == 'Yes') echo('checked="checked"'); ?>>

    Telephone: <input type="text" name="telephone" value=""><br>
    Email: <input type="email" name="email" value=""><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And so on and so forth for your next pages

Answer (score 0):

This does not include the code for generating the e-mail via PHP but is intend to show you how you can take the form input/checkbox selections and store there values to a SESSION ARRAY. Note that in this example: The form is submitting to itself by leaving the action="" blank, but normal would submit to a external PHP file for parsing/handling.

Also, im choosing to create a random number to represent the visitor to the form if not specifically set by $_POST['user']

```
<?php session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {$_SESSION['user']=rand(10,700);}
if (isset($_POST['user'])) {$id=$_POST['user'];} else {$id=$_SESSION['user'];}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
Sound 1:<input name="cb1" type="checkbox" value="sound1"><br>
Sound 2:<input name="cb2" type="checkbox" value="sound2"><br>
Sound 3:<input name="cb3" type="checkbox" value="sound3"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"><br><br>

<?php


if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST!=="") {
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $_SESSION['visitor']['sounds'][$id]=array(
      'selects'=>$_POST['cb1'].",".$_POST['cb2'].",".$_POST['cb3']
                                            );
                                      };

echo "For user ID:".$id." We echo the comma delimited stored SESSION array: ".$_SESSION['visitor']['sounds'][$id] ['selects'];
echo "<br><br>";
// Option 2 Explodes the comma delimited ['selects'] field to handle each choice seperately

$choice = explode(",",$_SESSION['visitor']['sounds'][$id] ['selects']);

echo "For an alternative, we EXPLODE the stored 'selects' field of the SESSION ARRAY and can then echo each out seperately"."<br><br>";

echo "User ".$id." Option 1 value was: ".$choice[0]."<br>";
echo "User ".$id." Option 2 value was: ".$choice[1]."<br>";
echo "User ".$id." Option 3 value was: ".$choice[2]."<br>";

echo "<br><br>";

echo "A last example we loop through the EXPLODED values and echo only those that were selected (ie: had a value)"."<br>";

foreach ($choice as $key => $value ) { if ($value!=="") {echo "Selection: ".$value."<br>";}   }

                                 }
?>
```